# Storage allocation for OneDrive for Business (On-Premise)

Tags: 2013, onedrive-for-business

Does anyone knows if there's a possible way you can configure the storage allocation in SharePoint Server 2013 OneDrive in MySite (On-Premise)?

Answer (score 1):

A personnal quota is automatically created by SharePoint for MySite. You may edit that quota definition, or assign a new quota to an individual MySite if you wish.
See these references:
 - [MSDN: Plan for My Sites in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500.aspx#storage)
 - [MSDN Blog (SP2010): My Site Default Quota
   Template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimmiet/archive/2012/07/22/10332361.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The OneDrive for Business document library is part of a user's My Site.By default, the quota for each user's My Site in SharePoint Server 2013 is 100 MB. If you plan to use the OneDrive for Business document library for users to store their files, you should increase this default quota limit.

Now you have to two options,

1. if you want to assign the same storage for everybody then you should create a quota template and assign to mysite.[Create, edit, and delete quota templates in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263223.aspx)
2. you can login to central admin > application Management,configure Quota and Locks. change here.

To set 100MB limit.

Please create a quota template using the above technet.
Now either go to central admin and change it for each mysite or use the below the powershell to apply all site collection in a web app.

```
$SPWebApp = Get-SPWebApplication http://portal

foreach ($SPSite in $SPWebApp.Sites)
{
    if ($SPSite -ne $null)
    {
        Set-SPSite -Identity $SPSite.url -QuotaTemplate ""
        $SPSite.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @waqas, is there a way to define it's limitation to 100mb for all users?

Comment: check the updated answer.

Comment: I already set the locks to 100MB but it also locks the storage capacity of other document library. I just need Onedrive to be set to 100MB.